# How do we modify the source of original Java classes?

Tags: java

Hi all I was wondering if I could modify and recompile a Java base class?

I would like to add functions to existing classes and be able to call these functions.

For example, I would like to add a function to [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), recompile it and use it for my project:

```
public char[] getInternalValue(){
      return value;
}
```

I was wondering how do we go about doing that?

Comment: Is it not better to write own implementations(utility classes) rather than playing an existing classes.

Comment: What are you trying to do by adding methods to existing classes? There is most certainly a better solution to whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: @casablanca For example, I want to gain access to the private fields of a class (`java.lang.String.value`)

Comment: @Pacerier: Don't, unless it's purely educational or for debugging.  Even then, don't.  Use the debugger.  Or at worst, use reflection.  Both will let you see the internal data of the class.

Comment: For your example, you know that Java's String class has a `toCharArray` method that will give you the contents of the string as a `char[]`, right?

Comment: I'm guessing that Pacerier is using `String` as a simple example and that this question is more general

Comment: Yes ninesided is right. Besides, `java.lang.String.toCharArray` isn't really the same as `java.lang.String.value`. toCharArray makes a copy of the internal value.

Comment: String class is immutable, any modifications to it will return a new copy. If you want something mutable (i.e. could be changed after initialing) then try `StringBuffer`.

Comment: In this case, you may need to watch out for unexpected behaviour with `-XX:+UseCompressedString` as it can use a `byte[]` instead of a `char[]` sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're referring to is called ["monkey patching"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch). It's possible in Java, but it isn't advisable and the results can be... uhh interesting. You can download the source for the String class, pop it into a JAR and prepend the bootclasspath with:

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:MonkeyPatchedString.jar
```

to replace the built-in String class with your own.

There's an interesting paper on this very subject [here](http://www.tedneward.com/files/Papers/BootClasspath/BootClasspath.pdf).

Comment: "With great power comes great responsibility" - Uncle Ben

Comment: The source is in the JDK. You can also add the JAR to the endorsed directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you do it, you get incompatible with the java.lang.String class, and with all classes, relying on java.lang.String, which is very, very rarely a good idea.

A second problem could be the license. For self-studying it is perfectly fine, but if you publish your code (compiled or in source) you should read the license terms carefully before.

Since the String class is declared final, you can't even inherit from String, and implement your PacerierString, which seems useful at first sight. But there are so many people, who would have implemented their little helpers, that we would get a lot of SpecialString classes from everywhere.

A common practice would be people, writing a class Foo, and adding a method

```
 public Foo toFoo () {
     // some conversion for String representation of Foo
 }
```

to their UniversalToolString.

You may, however, write a Wrapper, which contains a String. You might not pass your Wrapper to a method, which expects a String, but you would need to call its 'toString ()' method, if that happens to be a good candidate for that purpose.

```
   Foo foo = new Foo ("foobar", 42);
   foo.setMagic (foo.toString ().length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.

If you want to be evil, you can use reflection to access the byte array of a string. But of course there's no guarantee that that field will exist in the future as is... ok, it probably will, but caveat emptor.